# Maven SCM Section suppress artifactid

Tags: maven, configuration, maven-scm

I would like to configure the SCM server in a shared Maven parent pom in my organization so that none of the project poms (children) need to define this configuration. The configuration I would like to add looks something like this:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:hg:http://myscmserver.com/hg/${project.artifactId}</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:hg:http://myscmserver.com/hg/${project.artifactId}</developerConnection>
    <url>http://myscmserver.com/hg/${project.artifactId}/html</url>
</scm>
```

Unfortunately, Maven is automatically appending the artifactId to all the urls when it resolves these fields (when building Maven site). This is acceptable for the first two fields because I can just remove the reference to the artifactId property, but for the last field this results in a bad URL (http://myscmserver.com/hg/myArtifact/html/myArtifact instead of http://myscmserver.com/hg/myArtifact/html).

**Is there any was to suppress the automatic appending of the artifactId?** It is not feasible to change the child poms in this case.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: Any updates after almost two year?